# Python 3.5: To import a function from the same file, do you need to include the file name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

This is my main function:

```
    import kercalc as kc
    kermat=kc.kernel(args)
```

This is the content of kercalc.py:

```
    def kerfunc(args):
        <code>
        return value
    def kernel(args):
        <code>
        kermat=kerfunc(args)
        return kermat
```

Should I include an import statement inside the "kernel" function as follows?

```
    def kernel(args):
        from kercalc import kerfunc
        kermat=kerfunc(args)
        <code>
        return kermat
```

Or should I simply call my function?

Comment: simpply call it

Comment: No import needed. Just the call function by its name directly

Comment: try using python editors like pycharm. It will show syntactical errors as well

Comment: @advay.umare: I'll try that!

Comment: @Stack Thank you.

Comment: @PrakashPalnati Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no need to import. You can just call it by it's name.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to import as long as the function is in the same file. The need of import arises only when you are using a function that is present in another file. In your case simply use the function name whenever it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Once the file is imported, the function can be called from the command line.